# Extending attributes selector with Less Than & Greater Than in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

What would be the correct way to extend the jQuery attributes selector so that it supports Less Than and Greater Than?

I have some elements which contain a custom attribute SequenceNumber holding an integer. (Before anyone starts I cant use the data property (I think?) because this html is determined at runtime and generated serverside)

Either way. What I am looking to achieve is the ability to select a number of elements that contain a SequenceNumber BETWEEN X AND Y.

So basically something like this

```
$("#divSequenceGrid ul[SequenceNumber=>'1'][SequenceNumber<='10']").each(func);
```

Obviously I can do this by going

```
$("#divSequenceGrid ul").each(function (index, value) {
    //Push into an array those that fit my criteria 
});
```

But I'm wondering if there is a butter way?

Comment: Could filter possibly serve your needs? http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `.filter()`

```
  $("#divSequenceGrid ul").filter(function(){
        return  $(this).attr("sequenceNumber") >=1 && $(this).attr("sequenceNumber") <=10}).css("color", "red");
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/jFt9N/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery Selector expressions like this

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  sMore: function(e, i, m) { return parseInt($(e).attr('SequenceNumber')) >= m[3]; },
  sLess: function(e, i, m) { return parseInt($(e).attr('SequenceNumber')) <= m[3]; }
});

$(function () {
  alert($('div:sMore(2):sLess(4)').length);
});
```

Comment: you can also implode expressions
`var parts = m[3].split('-'), n = parseInt($(e).attr('SequenceNumber');
return n >= parseInt(parts[0]) && n <= parseInt(parts[1]);`